# Multiple Defintion Error when using external Library C++

Tags: c++, include

I have been hitting my head against the wall wondering why my c++ project is not compiling the external library SAMDTimerInterrupt.h

I am getting the following error:

```
C:Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\Stimulator.cpp.o: In function `TC3_Handler':
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:410: multiple definition of `TC3_Handler'
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\GVS_Simulator_V.1.8.ino.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:410: first defined here
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\Stimulator.cpp.o: In function `TCC0_Handler':
C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:423: multiple definition of `TCC0_Handler'
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\GVS_Simulator_V.1.8.ino.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:423: first defined here
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\Stimulator.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:399: multiple definition of `TCC_callback'
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\GVS_Simulator_V.1.8.ino.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:399: first defined here
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\Stimulator.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:398: multiple definition of `TC3_callback'
C:\Documents\vsCode builds\GVS_Stimulator_V1.8\sketch\GVS_Simulator_V.1.8.ino.cpp.o:C:\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SAMD_TimerInterrupt\src/SAMDTimerInterrupt.h:398: first defined here
```

Here are my includes structure:
[image]

[And here is a link to the external library](https://github.com/khoih-prog/SAMD_TimerInterrupt)

I noticed the library has both the definitions and declarations in the header file.
Is this the source of the problem? It does compile when I use only one main.cpp file.
(N.B. I am only using the library in Stimulator.cpp)

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Did you see [this notice](https://github.com/khoih-prog/SAMD_TimerInterrupt#howto-fix-multiple-definitions-linker-error) on the project page? Then again .. all three variants include a duplicate definition of TC3_Handler...

Comment: Can you forward-declare just the bits you need from SAMDTimerInterrupt.h in stimulator.h and #include the SAMDTimerInterrupt.h in a separate .\cpp file?

Comment: Yes I have seen this! But as you said the SAMDTimerInterrupt.h in src, src_cpp, src_h are identical!

Comment: I would file a bug with the library and create your own subset of SAMDTimerInterrupt for now.

Comment: Yes may have to that.

Comment: I have tried to forward declare `typedef SAMDTimerInterrupt SAMDTimer;
void SAMDTimer::stopTimer();
void SAMDTimer::detachInterrupt();
bool SAMDTimer::attachInterruptInterval(unsigned long interval, timerCallback callback);` but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239578/discussion-between-will-powell-and-botje).

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken to the creator of the library and decided to split the single .h file into a .h and .cpp so the declarations and definitions are separate. Hopefully he will update the SRC_CPP folder on Github to include this soon